# Automation UI - TextPattern in Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, ui-automation

I am currently playing around with Automation UI (C#) and Internet Explorer, and I am trying to see if there is a way to get the selected text from within a text box on a web page, such as the one that I am currently typing in right now.

After using inspect.exe and I inspect this text box (in internet explorer), it tells me IsTextPatternAvailable: true, however for some reason I cannot grab a text range within my test application.

```
AutomationElement element = focusedElement as AutomationElement;
if (element != null)
{
    foreach (AutomationPattern pat in element.GetSupportedPatterns())
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(pat.ProgrammaticName);
    }
}
```

The above will always tell me that there is a ValuePattern available, but never a TextPattern.

Could someone please let me know if what I am doing is possible, and if not what I should do to perhaps achieve something similar.

Comment: For web i will suggest to use selenium, https://www.seleniumhq.org/

Comment: @Aldo Your answer doesn't answer my question. Using Automation UI, can I do what I am trying to do.

Comment: If you are on Windows 8 or above , consider using UIA verify tool to inspect instead of  inspect.exe .  UIA verify uses newer version of UIA. Also, in your project instead of using required assemblies from GAC , use the ones shipped with [UIA utility](https://github.com/TestStack/UIAVerify)...The api remains the same so you won't have to make any changes to your code most probably. With utility you can also see what Automation patterns are available and can trigger them from the utility itself like invoke, get value , select ,etc.